# What is a 'Pocket Medic'?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology, tf2-medic

I've heard this term somewhere in TF2, and it is also sometimes used for other classes, such as 'Pocket Soldier', or 'Pocket scout', although most notably 'Pocket Medic'.

What does the "pocket" mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pocket medic is a medic that only heals his "pocket", that is one person in specific. The term is typically used pejoratively or neutrally, because the medic is supposed to keep the *entire* team healthy, not just his friend who's playing Heavy.

In random games, however, pocketing can be effective with friends or people with a clue. You know who you're ubering, you know you can trust them, you know you work well together. Just do make sure you share the heals as you build your uber.

A slightly different use of the word pocket is reserved in 6v6 competitive TF2 in order to distinguish the pocket soldier (who sticks with your medic) and the roaming soldier (who ambushes the *enemy* medic).

Comment: So can the term pocket apply to any other class? Pocket heavy? Pocket scout?

Comment: @Retrosaur That is correct, although pockets are almost exclusively soldiers, demomen or heavies (or, well, *medics*). See also http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Glossary_of_player_terms#P

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not exclusive to Team Fortress either - it applies to pretty much any class based online game. In WoW for example, you have 'pocket healers' - exactly the same deal as pocket medics in that it's a healer who follows a DPS around.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the different uses of the term, though I wouldn't call the difference "slight". The first is (generally) intended as an insult, while the second is a vital role in an effective team.

Comment: @AustinMohr The meaning is still only slightly different. The pocket soldier is called "pocket" because he's, uh, the medic's pocket. :)